# Is @EnableEurekaclient annotation is deprecated in spring boot version 3.9.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is @EnableEurekaclient annotation is deprecated in spring boot version 3.9.1 .Even though I add the eureka-client dependency in my spring boot project pom.xml file where ever I anntotated my spring boot main class with @EnableEurekaClient it showing cannot find this annotation

Comment: Please make sure you have the right version, the latest version of Spring Boot is 3.3.0.

Comment: It's in spring cloud not spring boot. You need spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client. See https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-eureka

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableEurekaClient` annotation is not required in latest spring versions. Simply adding `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` to dependencies will enable the client.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4022#issuecomment-915991198